# Unique axis labels with dplyr and ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

I am using `purrr` to make multiple `ggplot2` plots. How can I give each x-axis a unique name using a numeric string?

My best attempt (below) is only able to get the first value of the string, so the x-axis of all 3 graphs says `1% explained variance`, when I would like three different names of `1% explained variance`, `2% explained variance`, and `3% explained variance`. Thank you

```
library(tidyverse)

new<-c(1,2,3)

iris%>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  purrr::map2(.y = names(.),
              ~ ggplot(data=., aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
                geom_point()+
                labs(x=paste(round(new,2),'% explained variance', sep=''))
  )
```

Comment: looks like your using purrr not dplyr

Comment: Since you have already made the vector `new`, which is the same length as your list of data.frames, you can use that as your second list in `map2`.  So your `map2` would be like `%>% map2(new, ~ggplot(...` and your labels would be `x = paste( round(.y, 2)...` (the `.y` refers to the elements in the second list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `map2` we can specify the `.y` as `seq_along(.)` and then use that to index the 'new' because 'new' is a vector of length 3.

```
l1 <- iris %>% 
        split(.$Species) %>% 
        map2( seq_along(.), ~ 
             ggplot(data=., aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
                geom_point()+
                labs(x=paste(round(new[.y],2),'% explained variance', sep='')))
```

NOTE: If we are not using `names`, then simply pass the 'new' as `.y` (here the names of the `list` elements are not used)

---

The plots could be saved as a single pdf

```
library(gridExtra)
l2 <- map(l1, ggplotGrob)
ggsave(marrangeGrob(grobs = l2, nrow = 1, ncol =1), file = "plots.pdf")
```

Or save it as a single png with multiple plots on the same page

```
ggsave(marrangeGrob(grobs = l2, nrow = 3, ncol =1), file = "plots.png")
```

[image]